# nunique into new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, unique

I have some data in pandas:

```
df1
df1['ID_A'].nunique()
5
df2
df2['ID_B'].nunique()
6
df3
df1['ID_A'].nunique()
2
df4
df2['ID_B'].nunique()
9
```

and so-on until 200 `df`.

how to make new `dataframe` based on this `nunique`

my expected result looks like this:

```
  combine    ID_A  ID_B
  combine_1  5     6
  combine_2  2     9
```

thank you

Comment: What does your expected index look like??

Comment: index maybe if possible `combine_1` and `combine_2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with list of DataFrames and if necessary change index names by list comprehensions with f-strings:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_A':[1,2,3,4,5,5],
                    'ID_B':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_A':[1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1],
                    'ID_B':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

dfs = [df1, df2]
df = pd.DataFrame([x.nunique() for x in dfs])
df.index = [f'combine_{x+1}' for x in df.index]
df.index.name= 'combine'
print (df)
           ID_A  ID_B
combine              
combine_1     5     6
combine_2     2     9
```

If necessary filter only columns by list:

```
cols = ['ID_A', 'ID_B']
dfs = [df1, df2]
df = pd.DataFrame([x[cols].nunique() for x in dfs])
#filter only columns starting by ID_
#df = pd.DataFrame([x.filter(regex='^ID_').nunique() for x in dfs])
df.index = [f'combine_{x+1}' for x in df.index]
df.index.name= 'combine'
```

Comment: For advance, How about the index like this: first Combine_1 and second Group_1?

Comment: @Arief - If there are only `[df1, df2]` then `df.index = ['Combine_1','Group_1']` should working nice

Comment: how about if 200 df? and have a sequence number after combine and group?

Comment: so need `['Combine_1','Group_1', 'Combine_2','Group_2', ..]` ?

Comment: @Arief - It was question, if need this format, or another one :) Then I create solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191838/discussion-between-jezrael-and-arief).